# Construct an array to fit a Laplacian distribution when the data is big

Tags: python

I have a problem when I want to build an array to fit a laplacian distribution on it. The idea is that I have data of pixel intensities in an image of 360x180 pixels which has a big equator bias (see image below), and I want to see the Laplacian of it. My idea was to check row by row each pixel, and if its intensity is greater than a constant, I add to my "laplacian array" (which will be the one to be fitted) the number of pixels like that on that row. This isn't really clear so here is the code I used :

```
# For H=180, goes from -90 to 89 (to have 180 values)
heights = np.linspace(np.ceil(-H / 2), np.floor(H / 2), H + 1 if H % 2 == 0 else H)[:-1] 

lapl_arr = np.empty(0) # The "laplacian array"
points = data.copy()
epsilon = np.amax(data) / 10 # The constant which will be the threshold for the intensity

# For each row
for i in range(H):
    count = 1
    # Counts the number of pixels that have a greater "intensity" than epsilon
    for x in points[i]:
        if x >= epsilon:
            count += 1

    # Append the actual height 'count' times, to be able to fit a Laplacian distribution on it
    for val in range(count):
        lapl_arr = np.append(lapl_arr, heights[i])
```

Which computes the "laplacian array". It will be for example something like

```
lapl_arr
>>> [-90. -89. -88. -88. -88. ...  86.  86.  86.  87.  87.  88.  89.]
```

and then to fit it, simply :

```
# Fit the laplacian distribution
lin = np.linspace(min(lapl_arr), max(lapl_arr), len(lapl_arr))
mu, beta = laplace.fit(lapl_arr)
pdf_lapl = laplace.pdf(lin, mu, beta)
```

This actually works really well, as shown in the graph below. Now, my problem comes when I want to fit this Laplacian distribution on the result of this process for around 100 of this kind of images, to see the global bias for all the data. As each image have a bit less than 10'000 points with intensity greater than `epsilon`, our laplacian array will become waaaaaay to big... (Maybe it will work, but the process will surely be really long and the memory taken would be too great too).

Would you have a better idea on how to do this ?

Images:

[image: Laplacian distribution of the image]
[image: heatmap with equator bias]